# Setting a static IP

Tags: static-ip

Warning, noob question alert. I'd like to assign the same IP to my laptop once it is on my personal network. Unfortunately the DHCP is not assigning the same IP automatically. Is it sufficient to solely assign a static lease in my modem? I'm running into trouble when assigning a static IP on my MacBook (for example on other networks in a different range)

Thanks

Comment: Most routers have a feature to do this.  Have you tried looking at the manual for your router?

Comment: I have had problems with router-assigned static IPs. The solution is to set the IP address manually, making sure it's outside your router's DHCP pool range, while still within the same subnet. Note that this means you will need to re-enable DHCP when you want to use other networks.

Comment: Hi Ramhound, I figured that it  should be the static lease as shown in this pic: i53.tinypic.com/zk37ms.png Unfortunately my laptop did not receive the set IP after rebooting. Therefore I'm wondering whether it is my error, or some issue with the device.

Answer (score 0):

In most home networks you have a 'router' (actually a multi function device which acts as switch, Wireless access point, modem, firewall, router and DHCP server). Most of these support MAC Reservations.

That means that you can configure the 'router' so that you can keep DHCP turned on yet still get the same IP address everytime.

Comment: Hi Hennes, Thing is that I have set something my router calls a static lease, which I thought would do the trick that you mention. However after rebooting my laptop is not receiving the IP address as set in the router.

Comment: I have entered the MAC and IP here: http://i53.tinypic.com/zk37ms.png

Comment: Obvious questions but 1) Did you place the mark to enable it? 2) After making the reservation, did you try an ipconfig /release and ipconfig /renew?

Comment: I have placed the mark (checked too many times) and after making the reservation I have not tried to do a release and renew via the terminal, but I have tried the renew button in the setting which should have the same effect. Or am I wrong there?

Comment: Could be. Frankly I never tested it that way. I know there is a way to say "I have this IP. Can I please use it for another full lease period" (usually called at half lease time). And the DHCP server can answer both "OK" or "Nyet, use this instead" (or even NACK, but that would result in no IP or a 169 range).